# Match of an id value and extracing a string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

following problem:

I have a column with wrong Ids

[image: see here]

Now I want to watch those wrong Ids with another sheet where I have same Ids and the correct link I want to match with those Ids:

[image: see here]

So what I same up with is the following ->

[image: see here]

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'extract base'"B:F),"")"))
```

But obviously doesn't work haha. So basically very easy -> if the Id from Sheet 1 matches with the Id from Sheet two put in the second column (in my example custom_label) the value of sheet two column 2

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your current `VLOOKUP` formula is not structured correctly at all, and your sheet reference `'extract base'"B:F` is also not written correctly. Have you read the basic documentation on [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) usage and syntax?

Delete B2:B entirely.

Then place the following in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,'extract base'!B:F,5,FALSE))))`

This formula should provide results, if any, for all rows (assuming that your second sheet is, in fact, called exactly `extract base`).